# Voltage doubler ground and USB

Tags: usb, ground

I have the following voltage doubler:
[image: Voltage doubler]

Taken from an answer in another [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/652586/cant-find-suitable-center-tapped-transformer-for-use-with-ac-power-adapter) of mine.

This is to be used in an audio circuit, and the system will be connected to USB as well. Can the ground in this circuit be connected to USB ground, or will I have a bad day if I do that? If it can not, how would you go about solving this predicament?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I was a bit nervous that they might be at different voltage potentials, but that is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Because that power supply circuit (as drawn) is isolated.

I say "as drawn" because we don't know if you plan to do something unusual in the circuits you did not show us.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know what constitutes unusual. It's connected to the outlet through a certified ac/ac adapter, which is basically just a transformer (9v, not 24v). USB will power some chips (from phone or computer), and the circuit shown will power op-amps. Everything with common ground. All is good, right? Again, thank you for answering

Comment: "All is good, right?". Right.